# How to find accurate mobile signal strength and Service Provider Name?

Tags: iphone, ios, core-telephony

In my application i want to get the mobile network signal strength and network providers name,
in the below code it is returning the signal strength but i'm not feeling it as accurate ,because when the strength value went to 60% also the signal sticks are showing full.and the network provider name is returned as carrier.i'm calling this method for every 2 seconds.

```
-(void)UpdateLabelWithSignal{
   int str = CTGetSignalStrength();
   NSLog(@"SignalStrength:%d",str);
   NSLog(@"SignalStrength:%@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",str]);
   SignalLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",str];

}
```

//code for getting network provider name

```
    CTTelephonyNetworkInfo *netinfo = [[CTTelephonyNetworkInfo alloc] init];
    CTCarrier *carrier = [netinfo subscriberCellularProvider];
    NSLog(@"MY NAME:%@",carrier.carrierName);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15427507/how-to-find-out-carrier-signal-strength-programatically?rq=1

Comment: i din't understand that

Comment: This is a possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8254327/get-carrier-name-and-signal-strength-return-wrong-value-in-iphone) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15427507/how-to-find-out-carrier-signal-strength-programatically?rq=1) Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15427507/how-to-find-out-carrier-signal-strength-programatically/15531806#15531806) link for your solution

Comment: can u send me the code.

Comment: int CTGetSignalStrength();

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
 // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    
    while (true) {
        NSLog(@"signal strength: %d\n", CTGetSignalStrength());
        sleep(1);
    }
}

Comment: just confirming, you are not doing this on Simulator. Right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want it accurately update it for every few seconds.here is the code.

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
 {
  [super viewDidLoad];

  printf("signal strength: %d\n", CTGetSignalStrength());
 slimeDeathAnimTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.5 target:self selector:@selector(UpdateLabelWithSignal) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
  CTTelephonyNetworkInfo *netinfo = [[CTTelephonyNetworkInfo alloc] init];
  CTCarrier *carrier = [netinfo subscriberCellularProvider];
  NSLog(@"MY NAME:%@",carrier.carrierName);

  NSLog(@"mobileCountryCode = %@",carrier.mobileCountryCode);
  NSLog(@"mobileNetworkCode = %@",carrier.mobileNetworkCode);
  NSLog(@"isoCountryCode = %@",carrier.isoCountryCode);
  NSLog(@"allowVOIP = %d",carrier.allowsVOIP);

  }

-(void)UpdateLabelWithSignal{

int str = CTGetSignalStrength();
NSLog(@"SignalStrength:%d",str);
  NSLog(@"SignalStrength:%@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",str]);
SignalLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",str];

}
```